# Using patch-package on depency module

Tags: node.js, node-modules, patch-package

Here is the scenario.

I have a project (let's call it MyProject) that uses a 3rd party module, and is responsible to abstract some business rules. This has a small issue that needs to be patched since they're not releasing new versions.

`patch-package` works great on this project alone, however, MyProject is used as a module on many other projects so I don't have to duplicate said business rules.

When any other project installs MyProject, the `patch-package` tries to look for `./node_modules/MyProject/node_modules/3rdParty` instead of `./node_modules/3rdParty`.

Is there any way to fix that?

Or maybe an alternative?